# How to close the printscreen Popup in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to close the printscreen Popup but cant inspect the Path of it. So i am Using the robot class to close the popup ,is there any other way to close it??

Answer (score 0):

Option 1-
Use javascriptexecuter to close the pop up

Option 2-
use getwindowhandles->switch to window popup->Sendkeys(TAB)-> Sendkeys(Enter)

Comment: I used This "getwindowhandles" its for window Tab to get close  , I want my print Popup to get Closed.   for Ex - The PrintPopup Which comes while Taking a printout.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();//close alert
```

or

```
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {//Jump to new tab
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
driver.close();//close tab 
for (String windowHandleId : driver.getWindowHandles()) {//come back
        driver.switchTo().window(windowHandleId);
}
```